# Trouble binding to ApplicationController in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I just kicked off building a test app using Ember.js. I am trying to bind to the `ApplicationController` so that my name renders in the `application` template. I cannot get it to work!

I am following the information provided in http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/handlebars-basics/

Here is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/lib/handlebars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/lib/ember.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            <h1>Welcome to my test application</h1>
            <div>
                Hello, <strong>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</strong>!
            </div>    
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                MyApp = Ember.Application.create();
                MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
                    firstName: "Jones",
                    lastName: "Ross"
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output is:

```
Welcome to my test application
Hello, !
```

`firstName` and `lastName` appear to be `undefined`! No errors are generated.

Comment: what version of ember are you using above?

Comment: Can I see your ApplicationController?

Comment: Please add to your question if you can find a difference between your example and my JSBin, other than wrapping your app in a jQuery ready callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me. See [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uwufir/1/edit).

One note:

> You don't need to wrap the application in a jQuery `ready` callback. Ember will automatically defer initialization until DOM ready on its own.

Comment: Thanks Yehuda. I replaced my script references with the ones from your example and all works as expected. Something must be up with the scripts I have...

Comment: I have been playing around with the sample to try understand what happened here. When I reference the script from the ember site the sample fails. I cloned the JSBin sample here http://jsbin.com/animig/1/edit. I'm probably doing something stupid here, but would be grateful if you could take a look. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you were using Ember 1.0-pre2. You wanted to be using Ember from master (which will become pre3), which I used in my JSBin.

Comment: Nah... We **really** need to ship -pre3.